# Using a case/if in the where clause SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

So I have a list of items organized by date in two different categories, when switching the categories I sometimes run into an error that does not let the item go into the correct placement. The thing that is messing up the query is what I want to place in a case/if statement becuase it is only needed if there is an item with the same date, anyother time it throws off the whole query. Here is what I have, granted i know that that case does not work where it is or how it is, please work with me.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=0 THEN (SELECT MAX(Rotate)+1 FROM Table1 WHERE Vol=1)
ELSE MIN(o.Rotate) END as nRotate FROM Table1 o INNER JOIN Table2 s ON o.SID=s.ID 
WHERE s.Date >='7/30/2004' And s.ID<>100 And o.Vol=1 and 
Case s.DATE 
When '7/30/2004' then s.Sales>'Doe, Jane'
End
```

Comment: I did do research on this, for about two hours actually and did not find what I was looking for in anyone elses questions. If I had I wouldn't have asked. My problem was I was looking to hard at the case clause to think of anything besides that. Thanks for marking down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `case`:

```
WHERE s.Date >='2004-07-30' And s.ID <> 100 And o.Vol = 1 and 
      (s.date <> '2004-07-30' or s.Sales > 'Doe, Jane')
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my one query. I'll test it in multiple locations to make sure I get the answer I'm supposed to in every location. I'll mark answer after I try it out. I'm not fresh with SQL at the moment, its been a while.

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly across the board. I really should have thought of that though.... I was too stuck on the case clause to think of anything else besides that! I'll remember that from now on.